# How to iterate and click through list of instagram post web elements - selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iteration, instagram

So right now, I'm trying to build a bot that searches a particular hashtag on instagram, finds each user who made a post using that hashtag, and sends them a message.

I was able to collect a list of web elements from a particular div that represents every post on a "hash-tagged" page. And right now, my code will iterate through each element, trying to click on each post on the page.

However, what's struggling to click for me is how to move onto the next post after one post has been clicked on.

Pretty much, my current logic will just loop through the list, and repeadetly click on the first post on that page. Here's some code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait       
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By       
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time, urllib.request
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import sys
import os

# get prod.env vars
sys.path.insert(0, os.environ['HOME'])

dotenv_path = os.environ['HOME'] + '/prod.env'

load_dotenv(dotenv_path, override=True)    
locals().update(os.environ)

# Search up hashtags
PATH = "/Users/Nick/Desktop/chromedriver"

# headless options
# op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# op.add_argument('headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)
ig = driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
time.sleep(5)

# username and password input
username=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
password=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")
username.clear()
password.clear()
username.send_keys(ig_user)
password.send_keys(ig_pass)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
time.sleep(10)

# take care of popups
notnow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]").click()
time.sleep(10)
notnow2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]").click()
time.sleep(5)

# # search hashtag
query = "goodproblems"
page = driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + query)
time.sleep(5)

# driver.find_element_by_class_name('_9AhH0')
post_divs = [elem for elem in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_9AhH0')]

for post in post_divs:
    time.sleep(2)
    the_post = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]").click()
    time.sleep(4)
    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/div/li/div/div/div[2]/h2/div/span/a").click()
    time.sleep(3)

    try:
        message = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='button']").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.back()
        # cancel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div/button[5]").click()
        driver.back()
        driver.back()
        time.sleep(4)
       
        # message_input= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/textarea").send_keys("Sample message")
    except:
        print("no message button")
        # cancel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div/button[5]").click()
        driver.back()
        driver.back()
        driver.back()
        # cancel = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div/div/button[5]").click()

        time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Do you get any stacktrace error? Please elaborate a bit more

Comment: There is no error. I'm simply asking how to do a particular thing. When iterating through web elements, my code doesn't click the next post. It repeatedly clicks the same post, for each iteration.

Comment: if you mean the line where it says

`the_post = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]").click()`

Then its because you are pointing to an absolute xpath and always selecting the same element.
You should use a relative xpath to the post that comes from the iteration of post_divs

Comment: Why dont you just do
 
`for post in post_divs:
    time.sleep(2)
    post.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    ....`

Comment: Ah, I see. As far as you know, when I'm grabbing the xpath from the inspect element, if I select `full Xpath`, does that select an absolute xpath? Where, if I selected simply `Xpath` rather, that would select a relative xpath?

Comment: Also, I receive `StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` when I try the `post.click()` method, after the first post is clicked.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.